# How to join columns of same table under different query conditon

Tags: mysql

I am explaining here I have table name TB which contains three columns and data like this

```
Cl1.        Cl2           Cl3
0.             X.              A
0.             Y.               B
0.             Z.               C
1.             X.               a 
1.             X.               b
1.             X.               c
1.             Z.               d
```

And I output like this

```
Cl1.         Cl2.           Cl3.        No
0.             X.              A.          3
0.             Y.              B.          0
0.             Z.              C.          1
```

Here no column shows repetition of Cl2. Value when Cl1.=1 with respective value of Cl2. When Cl1. = 0 means for Cl1. = 1 here we can see for Cl.=1 and Cl2.=X it's value is repeated twice for Cl1.=1 similar when no match found for Cl1.=1 and Cl2.=Y no gives 0

I hope i have described my problem

I did many attempts but I didn't get any solution. My problem goes out of mind.
 My few attempts are like

```
Select Cl1. ,Cl2. ,Cl3. ,IF(Cl2.=(Select Cl2. From TB where Cl1.=1),Cl2. ,0) as no. 
From TB 
where Cl2.=0
```

I also try join type statement for the same table but it also didn't help me.
Please guys help me. I am new on stack overflow if I did any mistake in describing my question then sorry

Comment: Thanks GMB for formatting my question in correct order...

Comment: Welcome. Can you please explain why you have `No = 1` in the last output line, while there is no line with `Cl1 = 1`, `Cl2 = 'Z'` and `Cl3 = 'C'` in the sample data ? I would have thought this would result in`No = 0`

Comment: Because for Cl1=0  And Cl2=Z it comes once for Cl1=1

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, could you please specify, `Cl3` is not necessary in your task?

Comment: @Anton thanks for response. Cl3 is not necessary in our task but I need its data while contracting the result

Answer (score 0):

Try this, @Rajesh

```
SELECT 
    t1.cl1,
    t1.cl2,
    t1.cl3,
    IFNULL(cnt, 0) as No
FROM
(
    SELECT cl1, cl2, cl3 FROM tb WHERE cl1=0
) AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT cl2, COUNT(cl2) AS cnt FROM tb WHERE cl1 <> 0 GROUP BY cl2
) AS t2
ON t1.cl2=t2.cl2
```